# I cannot get the restart button to work on my stopwatch. Using Pythonista on iPhone

Tags: python, iphone, user-interface, global-variables, pythonista

```
import ui
from time import *
start = int(time())
def stop_time(sender):
    finish = int(time())
    total_time = int(finish - start)
    button1 = str("Your time is %i seconds." % (total_time))
    sender.title = None
    sender.title = str(button1)
```

## How do I allow the restart button to change the start variable?

```
def restart_time(sender):
    start = int(time())
    button2 = str("Stopwatch restarted.")
    sender.title = None
    sender.title = str(button2)
ui.load_view('stop_time').present('sheet')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you assign to an identifier for the first time in a function it creates a local variable, even if there's a global one with the same name.  Try this:

```
def restart_time(sender):
    global start
    start = int(time())
    button2 = str("Stopwatch restarted.")
    sender.title = None
    sender.title = str(button2)
```

From [the relevant entry in the Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere
>   within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable
>   is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is
>   implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.